# About the irreducibility of $p(x)=x^5+12ax^3+34bx+43c$ where $a,b,c$ are integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^5+12ax^3+34bx+43c$ where $a,b,c$ are integers. Then

1. $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$ if and only if $p(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb C$.
2. $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$ if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.
3. $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb C$.
4. $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

I can not understand which option is true.

Comment: Have you shown any of them to be true or false? Hint for a): The polynomial can never be irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Revise Gauss' lemma.

Comment: please someone response

Comment: Hint for 2 and 3: Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: do you at least see that $(1)$ does not make any sense (Thanks to Fundamental theorem of algebra)...

Comment: @jyrki here 2^2 ,3^2 divides 43c iffc=is a multiple of 2,3.

Comment: @ Tobias if p(x) is irreducible over Q then it will be irreducible over Z.idont know about converse.similarly if p(x) is irreducible over R then it will be irreducible over Q.and as every polynomial is reducible over C therefore p(x) is irreducible over R or reducible definitly it will be reducible over C,i don't know about the converse.

Comment: Do you see why the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ regardless of the choice of $a,b,c$?

Comment: yes .because it has odd degree ,it must have a linear factor in R

Comment: Ok, do you see why this means that 1. cannot be right? Can you find $a,b,c$ such that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: if we take a=b=1 and c=2 then by Eins. criteria that polynomial will be irreducible over Q and thus over Z.